# CSS Hover Menu Showing active menu item

Tags: html, css

I have the following css:

```
#nav ul li {float: left; margin-right: 10px; }
#nav ul li a { display: block; color: #fff; width: 100px; line-height:35px; background: #15612e; padding-left:16px;}
#nav ul li a:hover { background-color: #ea8206;}
```

This works as expected. What I would now like to do is have a class like this:

```
 a.active { background-color: #ea8206;}
```

Which I would like to assign to whichever menu item is selected on a page, but this is not working.

I assume it's to do with precedence, and have tried various combinations of:

```
#nav ul li a.active {background-color: #ea8206;}
```

I think I am just struggling with the right combination.

And the HTML is:

```
       <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Buy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sell</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Comment: We need your HTML as well, not just the CSS. Create a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) or post your HTML in your original question.

Comment: Have you added the class to your link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/moonspace/aKLUS/

This is all about specificity...
As you've already referred to 'a' classes in the CSS but prefixed them with '#nav ul' these will override a simple 'a.active' definition. So, add the '#nav ul' before a.active (as per the fiddle) and it'll work . . .

```
#nav ul li a { display: block; color: #fff; width: 100px; line-height:35px; background: #15612e; padding-left:16px;}
#nav ul li a:hover { background-color: #ea8206;}
#nav ul li a.active{ background-color: red; }
```

More useful stuff here : http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Thought I had tried that combinations. Obviously not. Many thanks